# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED how to fix?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, manifest

Today, I was working on an app. Testing testing testing.. and out of the blue, the app says Manifest Malformed. What is did first was undo what I changed, but that didn't help. I then copied a copy from this morning, but that was no good either.. Hope you guys can help, my manifest is below!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lahmob.swagdaddymcnugget"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >   

        <activity
            android:name="com.lahmob.swagdaddymcnugget.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.lahmob.swagdaddymcnugget.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.lahmob.swagdaddymcnugget.Webview"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.lahmob.swagdaddymcnugget.MusicPlayer"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_music_player" >
        </activity>   
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Because requested, the [LogCat](http://pastebin.com/0Sm200x3)

Comment: Please post the LogCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I fixed the problem myself. Turned out I just had to remove a corrupt lib file.

-Laurens